# How to find Total business count of employees in each category like doctor, lawyers, education, restaurants ...etc?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have different categories like doctor, lawyers, educations and professionals , restaurants like. in each category having employee id as foreign key of employee table. I want to get each employees total count of each category.

```
SELECT 
    emp_bioid, 
    COUNT(*) as Doctor, 
    (SELECT emp_name 
     FROM employees 
     WHERE emp_bioid = doctorsrating.emp_bioid
     ) AS emp_name 
FROM doctorsrating 
WHERE countryid=$countryid 
AND createdAt between '$fromDate' AND '$toDate'
GROUP BY emp_bioid;
```

I used this query to get doctors table count like wise i want to get other all the categories in single query like this. When i use this question i can get count of total business added by every individual employees. And more over doctors rating table having ratings points of doctors init. i want to get total count of each and every category individual by the employees.
`[ { 'emp_bioid' : '1234',  'emp_name' : 'XXXX',  'DoctorsCount' : '3',  'LawyersCount' : '0', 'EducationsCount' : '6',  'ProfessionalsCount' : '1',  'TravelspaCount' : '0',  'RestaurantsCount' : '0',  'LocalBusinessCount' : '6' },  {...} ]`

Comment: I am not clear what role doctorsrating plays but do you have similar lawyersrating.educationrating etc for all categories?

Comment: The query is wrong (1 - not full `GROUP BY`, 2 - ambiguous `emp_bioid`).

Comment: This looks like a problem of poor schema design

Comment: And please see about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Your query has no column called "category" and it is unclear where this data comes from.  And if you care about diverse jobs, it is unclear why you are using a table called `doctorsrating`.

Comment: If you just need the count of each category, it's the count of each table of each category of employees. And the way you design your system it seems hard to get all the counts in one query. But from your query it looks like you want more than the count..

Answer (score -2):

Can you share a snippet of made up data for the two tables? What is inside doctorsrating? Do each profession have a different table?

Can you extend your current query to something like this:

```
SELECT 
emp_bioid, 
COUNT(*) as Doctor,
COUNT(*) as Lawyer,
COUNT(*) as Educations,
COUNT(*) as Professionals, 
(SELECT emp_name 
 FROM employees 
 WHERE emp_bioid = doctorsrating.emp_bioid
   OR emp_bioid = lawyers.emp_bioid
   OR emp_bioid = educations.emp_bioid
   OR emp_bioid = professionals.emp_bioid
 ) AS emp_name 
FROM doctorsrating 
WHERE countryid=$countryid 
AND createdAt between '$fromDate' AND '$toDate'
GROUP BY emp_bioid;
```